How do you deploy a static Nuxt 3 app using AWS and Cloudfront?
I have a Nuxt 3 (v3.11.2) application that I'm trying to deploy to an AWS S3 bucket and serve using Cloudfront / Route53 for the domain.
In my nuxt.config.ts I'm using ssr: false and then running nuxi generate to create the static files. I then upload these to the s3 bucket using the aws-cli and invalidate my Cloudfront distribution.
I have a Cloudfront distribution behaviour (lambda trigger) to redirect traffic to /index.html:
function handler(event) {
    var request = event.request;
    var uri = request.uri;
    
    // Check whether the URI is missing a file name.
    if (uri.endsWith('/')) {
        request.uri += 'index.html';
    } 
    // Check whether the URI is missing a file extension.
    else if (!uri.includes('.')) {
        request.uri += '/index.html';
    }

    return request;
}

If I visit the site directly on the https://examplesite.com everything is great and I can navigate around. If I'm in a sub directory https://examplesite.com/something/:id everything works until I reload the page. If I refresh the page I get a AccessDenied error from Cloudfront.
Update
It looks like it's possible to just use Nuxt 3 in SPA mode using the following nuxt.config.ts:
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  ssr: false,
  hooks: {
    'prerender:routes': function ({ routes }) {
      routes.clear()
    },
  },
  router: {
    options: {
      hashMode: true,
    },
  },
})

It does mean that the router uses hashes (#) to delimit the routes and you lose SEO. Suggestions on how to do this another way are very welcome.

Looks quite complex of a setup, don't you want to use Netlify/Vercel or Cloudflare pages rather? What are the benefits of having such a complex setup?

We use AWS in house for prod, S3 is cost effective to host the site and cloudfront should improve the speed for serving the content. Is this not a standard setup?

S3 is not the fastest and not that cost effective either tbh. Also for a basic SPA app there are faster, easier and cheaper places to host it. AWS' DX is awful too... You should probably keep everything on Cloudflare and ship it from there for better speed.

It's honestly not a config problem but a platform one. Don't Nuxt docs have a part on how to host it on AWS ? Otherwise, I recommend using Netlify or litetralg anything else. Will work in 60s and is easy to use.

You need to set up a custom 404 response on cloudfront and custom error document in s3. Use the same values I have in the attached images. You shouldn't need any of the custom functions you've created.


This resolved my issues with dynamic routes returning 404 and not rendering.
